# Redirecting non-www to www in IsapiRewrite

Tags: isapi-rewrite, isapi-redirect

I am trying to redirect calls to http://mydomain.com to http://www.mydomain.com.
Is there a simple way to do it in IsapiRewrite file?

I have tried the following but it is not working:

RedirectRule ^mydomain.com$  www.mydomain.com    [R=301]

Also tried this:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com     [I]

RewriteRule (.*)  http\://www.mydomain.com$1  [I,RP]

Any idea what I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} (on)?
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?!www\.)(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)
RewriteRule .? http(?%1s)://www.%2%3 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: this doesn't work. Any other suggestions? One error I got in the log file was R cannot be used with RewriteRule, use RedirectRule instead. So I tried without R=301 as well as RedirectRule. Neither worked.

Comment: What product is it? I assumed it's ISAPI_Rewrite 3. If it's 2 then try RP instead of R=301

Comment: This worked for me:

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?!www\.)(.+)$ [I]

RedirectRule (.*) http://www.%1%2 [R=301]